# pause/play video on click not working javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to pause and play a video on click using jquery, by checking if the video is paused already if it is not, onclick of a button pause the video.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="footage">
  <video width="320" height="240" autoplay muted playsinline loop id="videoMob">
    <source src="./img/NoOne.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
<div class="play">
  <i class="fa fa-pause fa-1x"></i>
</div>
```

```js
$('.play').click(function() {
  if ($('#videoMob').paused) {
    $('#videoMob').play();
  } else {
    $('#videoMob').pause();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The `paused` property and `play()` and `pause()` methods are members of the Element object, not a jQuery object. As such you need to amend your logic slightly to retrieve the Element:

```
$('.play').click(function() {
  var video = $('#videoMob')[0];
  video.paused ? video.play() : video.pause();
});
```

Comment: Just too fast :(

Comment: @user10629012 no problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped. That also goes for your previous questions too